# Informatica and Bulk mode for ODBC driver

Tags: odbc, informatica

Is there way to enable bulk mode for odbc driver. I want to use IMDG driver that supports bulk mode but the Informatica shows this error "The session failed to run because bulk mode is enabled in the DSN entry.       Disable bulk mode for ODBC."

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps, you must have admin access to enable/disable it though I believe.
https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/18/486011.aspx

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't use Sql Server. So my question is to could I use  the bulk mode for other ODBC driver.

Comment: @PavelVinokurov : did you get the solution ? also which other ODBC driver you were trying to connect?